# Trying to get color value of pixel

Tags: macos, colors, pixel, nsimage

I'm trying to read the color value of a pixel in a tif image but I can't fihure out the correct way to do it. I'm using OSX and my approach is as follows:

```
NSImage *picture = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"bais2.tif"]; //file is located in resoureces folder.
NSBitmapImageRep *imageRep = [[picture representations] objectAtIndex:0];

NSColor* color = [imageRep colorAtX:10 y:10];
NSLog(@"%f %f, %f", [color redComponent], [color blueComponent], [color greenComponent]);
```

The problem is that for some reason the logged values in NSLog always becomes 0.0000000....

I have also tried to use:

```
NSBitmapImageRep* imageRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithData:[picture TIFFRepresentation]];
```

instead of `[[picture representations] objectAtIndex:0]` but the result is the same.

I get no error messages or warnings, but I think there is something wrong when i load the picture?
Please help me, what am i doing wrong? And is there a better way to read pixel color data?

Comment: nslog picture and tell if it prints?

Comment: No... I get null when i log the image... *confused*.

Comment: So here is the problem, you are unable to read the bais2.tif into picture

Answer (score 2):

Your error is here:

```
NSImage *picture = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"bais2.tif"];
-------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^
```

You can use:

```
NSImage *picture= [NSImage imageNamed:@"bais2.tiff"];
```

Or :

```
NSImage *picture = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"bais2.tiff"];
```

Comment: Thank you Anoop. You solved my problem.
I don't understand why it must end with .tiff. The filename ends with .tif.

Comment: are you sure it is `bais2.tif` not `bais2.tiff`. Anyways your problelm is solved :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 NSData *someNSData = [Image TIFFRepresentation];
 NSBitmapImageRep *someNSBitmapImageRepData = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithData:someNSData];
 NSSize imageSizee = [someNSBitmapImageRepData size];

 CGFloat y = imageSize.height - 100.0;
 NSColor* color = [someNSBitmapImageRepData colorAtX:100.0 y:y];

 NSLog(@"color = %@",color);
```

output : color = NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace 1 1 1 1